# Terraform: Attaching an unmanaged IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform version: 12

We have a legacy, unmanaged by Terraform IAM role that I'd like to reference from an `aws_iam_policy_attachment` block and I attempted the following:

```
  resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "example-attach" {
  name = "example-attach"

  roles = [ 
    aws_iam_role.managed-role.name, 
    "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/unmanaged-role"
  ]

  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.example-policy.arn
}
```

Dry-run works fine but when applying TF says:

> – ValidationError: The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-

Is there a way I can just reference the unmanaged role without defining it in TF? Or is there some non-destructive way of declaring it that doesn't change anything to do with the unmanaged role?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `roles`, you are providing role ARN, not role name.

Therefore, instead of ARN, you should use its name:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "example-attach" {

  name = "example-attach"

  roles = [ 
    aws_iam_role.managed-role.name, 
    "unmanaged-role"
  ]

  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.example-policy.arn
}
```

You can also use [data_source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_role)

```
data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "unmanaged-role"
}
```

and the reference it in your resource:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "example-attach" {

  name = "example-attach"

  roles = [ 
    aws_iam_role.managed-role.name, 
    data.aws_iam_role.example.name
  ]

  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.example-policy.arn
}
```